# Jquery scroll with scrollTop Position is really slow to scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have infinity scroll and each time the top scroll reach to certain part of the div, it loads a new content until its over. But each time it loads, it get very slow. It happens when I put some code inside of `.each` function, and that my scroll becomes really slow, which is annoying. I don't know how to fix it

```
function scrollAnimationFrame(ticking, windowHeight, tabSelected){
    if (!ticking) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
            scrollEvent(tabSelected, windowHeight);
            ticking = false;
        });
    }
    ticking = true;
}

function scrollEvent(tabSelected, windowHeight) {
    var activeTab = document.getElementsByName(tabSelected)[0]
    var divResults = activeTab.getElementsByClassName('div-content');
    var scrollY = window.scrollY || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    var pos = $(window).scrollTop();

    var scrollY = window.scrollY || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

    $(divResults).each(function(i, el){
        var posOutsideDiv = $(el).offset().top + $(el).outerHeight();
        var inside = (scrollY >= $(el).offset().top && scrollY <= posOutsideDiv - 150)

        if(inside){
            toggleThead(el, "visible");
        } else if(scrollY >= $(el).offset().top && scrollY <= posOutsideDiv + $(document).height()){
            toggleThead(el, "hidden");
        } else {
            toggleThead(el, "visible");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What gets slow? Scrolling the page entirely or it's slow only when you're appending new elements?

Comment: Are you trying to scroll to the top of the browser window?  Or to the top of an element?  It might be because you are doing your math inside the .each().  If you have a lot of rows of data, then it is calculating each element  that has been posted, looping and then scrolling to the top of each until it hits the one you want. Can  you just scroll to the top of the parent element?   Do you have an example of what you want to accomplish?

Comment: @Martin the page get slower each time it appends new elements

Comment: @ClosDesign I'm check the top page of the window if inside of the div element. And I tested with 5  elements and its really slow, and the max is 180.

Comment: Can you show where you call `scrollAnimationFrame()`? Because the `.each` loop get's called just once here so it should effect the page performance.

Comment: Check here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I thought it was javascript that the scroll is getting slower each time appending a new content. So I checked at AngularJs and I was reusing the directive template. So basically create two directives for each template and voilá(Hated doing this). No more slow scroll.